# How to Use Enum Flags with EF 6.1.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I think my query is not working because of the enum flag I have.

```
   [Flags]
    public enum Permissions
    {
        None = 0,
        Read = 1,
        Write = 2,
        Delete = 4,
        Full = 8
    }


dbContext.UserStorages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Permission.HasFlag(Permissions.Write));
```

In my sql database the column is an "int" column. and right now has a value of "8" if I change it to Permissions.Full then I will get the record back.

Comment: no EF will not translate HasFlag to SQL you have to do it by your self before you pass it to the query : myFlag = None | Read and pass myFlag to the firstOrDefault

Comment: You can however use bitwise operators and they will be translated (e.g. `x => (x.Permission & Permissions.Write) != 0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Permissions.Full` shouldn't be 8 but 7 if it means Read + Write + Delete. In binary

```
Read   -> %001
Write  -> %010
Delete -> %100
Full   -> Read | Write | Delete -> %001 | %010 | %100 -> %111 -> 7
```

In your case you are asking whether the second bit (i.e. `%0010`) is set in `%1000` which obviously it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. I think this was it. I was wondering about that but the example I copied from had 8. I guess it was wrong as well.